# PyTorch: Using a dataset of differently sized inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a semantic segmentation model which takes any size image, and it seems that its not supported by default to allow for differently sized model inputs.

My current approach leads to the error:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 577, 1691] at entry 0 and [3, 733, 1691] at entry 1
```

On the beginning of the loop:

```py
loop = tqdm(dataloader) # Without this line the error still occurs.
for batch,(data,targets) in enumerate(loop):
```

I have super simple dataset:

```py
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PyTorch dataset class
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import torch
import torchvision
import os
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import numpy as np
import math

class AidaDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(
        self,
        image_dir, 
        mask_dir, 
        transform=None,
        target_transform=None,
    ):
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.mask_dir = mask_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
        self.images = os.listdir(image_dir)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        # print("__getitem__ {index} start")

        img_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir,self.images[index])
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_dir,self.images[index].replace(".jpg",".png"))
        # image = torch.tensor(np.array(Image.open(img_path).convert("L"))) # 1 channel input
        image = torch.tensor(np.array(Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB"))) # 3 channel input

        # image = image.unsqueeze(0) # 1 channel input - Image needs channel dimension, even if its 1. Adds channel dimension to front.
        image = torch.movedim(input=image,source = 2, destination = 0) # 3 channel input - Move channels dimension to front

        # assert len(image.shape) == 3
        # assert image.shape[0] == 1 # 1 channel input
        # assert image.shape[0] == 3 # 3 channel input

        mask = torch.tensor(np.array(Image.open(mask_path).convert("L"), dtype=np.int))

        # assert len(mask.shape) == 2
        # assert mask.shape == image.shape[-2:]

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            mask = self.target_transform(mask)

        return image.type(torch.float32), mask
```

With:

```py
dataset = AidaDataset(image_dir=IMG_DIR, mask_dir=MASK_DIR)
train_len, val_len = int(len(dataset) * (1-VALIDATION_PROPORTION)), int(len(dataset)*VALIDATION_PROPORTION)
train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset,[train_len,val_len])

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True)

model = TiledUNet(out_channels = number_of_classes)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = class_weights)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=LEARNING_RATE)
scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    train_fn(train_dataloader,model,loss_fn,optimizer,scaler)
    test(val_dataloader,model,loss_fn)
```

Where:

```py
def train_fn(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, scaler):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    loop = tqdm(dataloader)
    for batch,(data,targets) in enumerate(loop):
        data = data.to(device=DEVICE)
        # By default our mask is one-hot encoded so the channels dimension is already added
        targets = targets.to(device=DEVICE)

        # forward
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            predictions = model(data)
            # print(f"predictions.shape: {predictions.shape}, targets.shape: {targets.shape}")
            # assert False
            loss = loss_fn(predictions,targets)
        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if DEVICE == "cuda":
            scaler.scale(loss).backward()
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
        else:
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())
```

Resulting in the full error:

```
running
  0%|                                                                                                                           | 0/2969 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 197, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 175, in main
    train_fn(train_dataloader,model,loss_fn,optimizer,scaler)
  File "train.py", line 51, in train_fn
    for batch,(data,targets) in enumerate(loop):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1178, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 56, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 577, 1691] at entry 0 and [3, 733, 1691] at entry 1
```